# Change registry - no administrators group has write permission - SYSTEM only

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry, permission-denied, regedit

I am trying to change the "FriendlyName" registry using PowerShell.
The write permission for this registry is set for the SYSTEM, but the administrators' group is not allowed to modify it.

Normally I would use:

```
"New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ACPI\PNP0501\1 -Name FriendlyName -Value 'NewName' -Force"
```

But, of course, access is denied.

How can I change registry when only the SYSTEM is allowed to do this?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Search on _taking ownership_. And in future ask how to use computers questions on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com.

Comment: Then why PowerShell tag has almost 80k questions here?